Error During Windows 11 Installation (Setup has failed to validate product key)
I am trying to upgrade from Windows 10 to 11. My device supports all Windows 11 requirements except the processor requirement (I run an Intel i5 7th Gen 7400). I tried to update with both the direct Windows media creation / direct iso as well as creating a USB with Rufus (I want to upgrade to Windows 11 without performing a full format)


When installing from an USB boot of the installation media, you can skip entering the product key. Can't you also do this when running setup from the mounted ISO?

And what product key did you enter? A Windows 11 key that you purchased?

Why are you trying to install Windows 11 instead of upgrading Windows 10 to Windows 11? You should be upgrading to Windows 11 within Windows 10 if you want to perform an upgrade to Windows 11 instead of a clean install of Windows 11.  You cannot upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 if you boot to the WinPE. You are going to need to explain if you are running setup.exe from within Windows or if you are booting to the WinPE by editing your question.

The reason for my last comment is because a license check is happening and that’s why I believe your booting to WinPE instead of launching Setup.exe from within Windows or installing through WU.

@Ramhound I was running the setup.exe after unzipping the iso and the issue was solved by using a default windows ome activation key and then switching back to the key I was using (I had purchased the key a while back for windows 10)

If you have an activated Windows 10 installation and are upgrading to Windows 11, then you do not need enter any activation key. Windows 11 will automatically be activated. This is true even if you erase Windows 10 and do a clean install of Windows 11.

You shouldn’t have to use the default license key, which obviously can’t be used to activate Windows, nor your original key since Windows 10 and Windows 11 both support a digital activation. Your description only raises we questions

@Ramhound, I am on a desktop which does not have a product key saved on the motherboard and as to why is it not digitally activated my win 10 was also activated by manually typing the key in the orignal installer when I installed it.

@David Anderson I think this would explain my situation better.....  "I am on a desktop which does not have a product key saved on the motherboard "

@ShoaibSadiq - Your installation should still be digital since this wasn’t the first time you had installed it.

@Ramhoound I dont know what went wrong then tbh. But even after I typed in the generic product key windows still showed activated and showed Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your microsoft account(if this is what you meant by it is digitally activated then yes it does show that but also said in the installed that it was unable to verify it but changing it manually solved the issue and I could go back to manually typing my key it showed the activated statement through out the whole time even when I typed the generic key)
